# Outlets not working but have power

Tags: electrical

Ok, once again thanks for the help with my last problem which stemmed from this the original problem.

Here it goes.

Half my garage doesn’t have power. Well let me rephrase. None of the outlets are working in half my garage. They set off the no touch volt meter. I checked them with a multi-meter and they are all reading zero.

I changed out the plugs on two outlets no luck. Although the last outlet before they stop is only working in one plug.

I believe they are on a different circuit maybe. If that’s what u call it. I believe instead of jumping from one to next where my owner stops has its own wires. I’m gonna draw up a sketch of garage and put in here.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes for the half-working outlet and the switch please?  Also, I take it the light controlled by the switch *does* work?

Comment: If I understand the picture and the red arrows correctly, you are referring to a 30 A fuse. Normally receptacles are on 15 A (with 14 AWG wire) or 20 A (with 12 AWG wire). 30 A is normally for big stuff (e.g., dryers, heaters, etc.) and not "regular" receptacles.

Comment: At your last working outlet, can you pull it out and see if it is 1 or 2 circuits?If it is 1 circuit, then the metal tab/strip should still be attached. If it is 2 seperate circuits, and you can verify this, the metal tab/strip will be missing. If it is 1 circuit, and the metal tab/strip is missing, this is why your outlets past there don't work.

Comment: What metal strip where does it go

Comment: Yes light works

Comment: The fuses in there are what was in when I bought house

Comment: "*I believe they are on a different circuit maybe. If that’s what u call it. I believe instead of jumping from one to next where my owner stops has its own wires*"  **I am having a hard time deciphering what that is saying**. Possibly because of the punctuation, i would change it but i am not clear on the **exact** meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> They set off the no touch volt meter. I checked them with a multimeter and they are all reading zero.

Combining these, you may have a situation where both prongs of the outlet are at 120V:

- the multimeter shows no voltage between the prongs
- the no-touch meter measures an electromagnetic field.

If this is true, you have a wiring fault and it's time to call a licensed electrician.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just jump from the other circuit that is working or you could use a cable tracker to see which circuit they are on. One of the Edison or bus fuses could be blown.

Comment: I’ve changed all the fuses the one with the arrows is the one that would blow sometimes for those outlets